# ToArray doesn't seem to be working Moq's Verify method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to verify a method call using Moq with the following code.

```
var _payload= new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("Test", TestNum),
    new KeyValuePair<string, object>("FirstRunTime", DateTime.Parse("19-Apr-2001 09:30:00"))
};
```

The above List definition is common to both the following pieces of code.  I'd originally tried this::

```
mockMessageProcessor.Verify(service => service.QueueMessage(
    DateTime.Parse("19-Apr-2016 10:05:00"), 
    "TestJobKey",
    _payload.ToArray()), Times.Once);
```

This fails saying there was no invocation of the above method with those parameters. Putting the same thing in a variable works.

```
var payloadArray = _payload.ToArray();
mockMessageProcessor.Verify(service => service.QueueMessage(
    DateTime.Parse("19-Apr-2016 10:05:00"), 
    "TestJobKey",
    payloadArray), Times.Once);
```

The above verify works. Just wanted to know why this is happening.

Comment: Since `_payload.ToArray()` returns a new array on each invocation, I'm thinking Moq validates if they're the exact same object (which they're then not since they came from 2 different invocations) and not if they contain the same data.

Comment: Because `Equals(_payload.ToArray(), _payload.ToArray() == false` whilst `Equals(payloadArray, payloadArray) == true`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. @Aron, that makes sense.

Comment: @Aron, If you can add an answer with what you've put in the above comment, I can select it as the answer for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting Aron from the comment above:

Because `Equals(_payload.ToArray(), _payload.ToArray()) == false` whilst `Equals(payloadArray, payloadArray) == true`